# how OpenCV Java Detect ellipse, circle face in an image

Tags: java, opencv

Please, How we can use OpenCV Java , to detect an ellipse of face form in an image.

The code below is used for rectangular.

```
CvRect rect = new CvRect();
rect.x(100);
rect.y(100);
rect.width(200);
rect.height(200);
```

how can we make it ellipse or circle ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `rect` with pre-defined dimensions, you can simply use [`cv::circle()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#circle), to draw circles instead of rectangles on a given canvas.

Comment: The cv:: circle () is in C++ iam using Java

Comment: It must be having `Imgproc.circle()` API